# Py2Neo: Cypher Query

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I am trying to make the following Cypher query:

```
start me = node:actors(actor = 'Tom Baker') , you = node:actors(actor = 'Peter Davison') match p = you-[*1..3]-me return p
```

using the Dr.Who dataset available in the neo4j site. It gives correct results in the Neo4j console as well as correct result in Py2Neo. However now I want to make the query in such a way such that

```
x='Tom Baker'
y='Peter Davison'
```

and make the same query using the variables x and y. However I dont know the escape sequence for Py2Neo. I tried the below query

```
"start me = node:actors(actor = \'.x.\') , you = node:actors(actor = \'.y.\') match p = you-[*1..3]-me return p"
```

but it didnt work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use parameters instead, named parameters in cypher are {name} and you pass a hash/dictionary with the name-value pairs along with the query.

```
start me = node:actors(actor = {me}) , 
you = node:actors(actor = {you}) 
match p = you-[*1..3]-me 
return p

params: {"me":"Tom Baker","you":"Peter Davison"}
```

Comment: To embed the values within the Cypher query string you'd need to use either the `%` syntax or string formatting (http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). That said, Michael's answer is far better than either of these and will avoid weird quoting issues. The params can be passed as a dictionary argument to cypher.execute (http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/cypher.html#py2neo.cypher.execute).